pylint --generated-members doesn't ignore class protobuf class
Would anyone of you know how to configure pylint to error for the following module?
Option doesn't work for 'vox_api.api_pb2.*' and 'vox_api.*', but works for 'Response':
Results:
$ pylint --generated-members='vox_api.api_pb2.*' src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py -v
Using config file /storage/amoje/Sync/area22/jct/.pylintrc
************* Module pyjct.jarvis_response
src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py:17:13: E1101: Module 'vox_api.api_pb2' has no 'Response' member (no-member)
src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py:18:12: E1101: Module 'vox_api.api_pb2' has no 'Response' member (no-member)
src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py:19:11: E1101: Module 'vox_api.api_pb2' has no 'Response' member (no-member)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 4.83/10 (previous run: 4.83/10, +0.00)
Checked 1 files, skipped 0 files


pylint --generated-members='vox_api.*' src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py -v
Using config file /storage/amoje/Sync/area22/jct/.pylintrc
************* Module pyjct.jarvis_response
src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py:17:13: E1101: Module 'vox_api.api_pb2' has no 'Response' member (no-member)
src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py:18:12: E1101: Module 'vox_api.api_pb2' has no 'Response' member (no-member)
src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py:19:11: E1101: Module 'vox_api.api_pb2' has no 'Response' member (no-member)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 4.83/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, -5.17)
Checked 1 files, skipped 0 files

Works for --generated-members="Response":
$ pylint --generated-members="Response" src/pyjct/jarvis_response.py -v
Using config file /storage/amoje/Sync/area22/jct/.pylintrc

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
Checked 1 files, skipped 0 files

$ pylint --version
pylint 3.3.1
astroid 3.3.5
Python 3.12.3 (main, Sep 11 2024, 14:17:37) [GCC 13.2.0]

Snippet of the code:
import vox_api.api_pb2 as api

@dataclass
class JarvisResponse:
    session: api.Response

EDIT
I have just figured out that it works for: --generated-members='api.Response'.
